# independence of random variables with random index

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, independence

Let $\{X_i\}$ be iid real random variables. And N be a random variable, taking values in $\mathbb{N}$.

My question is if $X_{N}$ has the same distribution as $X_{N+1}$, because of the iid assumption? If yes, have you any suggestions how to start this proof? Thank you verry much in advance!

Comment: Start with an arbitrary set $A$, and think about the quantities $\mathbb P(X_N \in A)$ and $\mathbb P(X_{N+1} \in A)$. Break each event up into disjoint events by using the fact that $N$ can only take values in the natural numbers, and then use the fact that the $X_i$ are identically distributed (note : you don't need independence) to conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much, so i think the decomposition you mean is:            $$\mathbb{P}(X_N \in A )=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(\{X_k\in A\}\cap \{N=k\}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(\{X_{k+1}\in A\}\cap \{N=k\}) $$                        
                                                                  ? However i don't see why the last step holds true?

Comment: Actually, this is a good question and I'm not sure what the answer is if you allow $N$ to depend on the $X_i$. The above last step is not true, definitely not on a second glance. Of course, if $N$ is independent of the $X_i$ then things are good, but if it depends on the $X_i$ then I actually don't think the statement is true.

Comment: In fact, the statement is *obviously false* if $N$ depends on the $X_i$, *even if* the $X_i$ are iid. Example : let $X_i$ be iid uniform random variables on $[0,1]$ and let $N$ be the largest index such that $X_1,\ldots,X_N \in [0,\frac 12]$. Then, $X_{N} \in [0,\frac 12]$ and $X_{N+1} \notin [0,\frac 12]$ by choice of $N$. Hence, $X_N$ and $X_{N+1}$ don't have the same distribution. You probably need $N$ to be independent of the $X_i$.

Answer (score 2):

We have:$$P\left(X_{N}\in A\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left(N=n\right)P\left(X_{N}\in A\mid N=n\right)=$$$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left(N=n\right)P\left(X_{n}\in A\mid N=n\right)$$
and:

$$P\left(X_{N+1}\in A\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left(N=n\right)P\left(X_{N+1}\in A\mid N=n\right)=$$$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P\left(N=n\right)P\left(X_{n+1}\in A\mid N=n\right)$$

So the answer is "yes" if: $$P\left(X_{n}\in A\mid N=n\right)=P\left(X_{n+1}\in A\mid N=n\right)\text{ for every }n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Sufficient conditions for this are:

- $N$ and $X_n$ are independent for every $n\in\mathbb N$.
- The rv's $X_{n}$ have identical distribution.

Comment: Thank you verry much! Unfortunatly i don`t have that N is independent of $X_n$, i just have the second assumption. More precisely i have $N=N(n)$ and $N(n)$ depends on $X_1, ..., X_{n+1}$ but not on $X_{k}$ for $k>n+1$... Is in this case somehow $X_{N(n)+1}\sim X_{N(n)+2}$

Comment: I was afraid of that and somehow already suspected that independence of $N$ wrt the $X_n$ would lack. My answer is not of much value for you. The conditions I mentioned are sufficient but not necessary so there is still hope on $X_N\sim X_{N+1}$. But I cannot help you with it.

Comment: See my comments below the question. Even if the $X_i$ are iid, the statement can be false if $N$ depends on the $X_i$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $X \overset{d}{=} Y$ if $\mathbb{E}(f(X)) = \mathbb{E}(f(Y))$ for all continuous bounded functions $f$. Now observe,

$$
\mathbb{E}(f(X_N)) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(f(X_N)|N)) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(f(X_n)|N) \vert_{n=N} ) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(f(X_{n+1})|N) \vert_{n=N} ) = \mathbb{E}(f(X_{N+1}))
$$

as long as $\mathbb{E}(f(X_{n+1})|N) = \mathbb{E}(f(X_{n})|N)$.

If we don't know that $X_k|N$ are identically distributed, then the proof doesn't go through. Here is a counter example: Let $X_k \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0, 1)$ and take $N = \mathbb{I}(X_1 > 0)$.